# Using __json_schema__ to serialize enums in Pydantic v2

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I'm working on cleaning up some of my custom logic surrounding the json serialization of a model class after upgrading Pydantic to v2. With Pydantic v1, I could write a custom `__json_schema__` method to define how the object should be serialized in the model. It appears that Pydantic v2 is ignoring this logic. Does anyone know what process replaced this? I've attached an example of the string of objects that I've customized for this purpose.

```
class ExtendedStr(str):
    _display: str

    def __new__(cls, value: str, display: Optional[str] = None) -> ExtendedStr:
        s = super().__new__(cls, value)
        s._display = display if display else value
        return s


class ExtendedEnum(ExtendedStr, Enum):
    def __init__(self, value: ExtendedStr) -> None:
        self.value._display = value._display

    @classmethod
    def values(cls) -> List[str]:
        return [c.value for c in cls]

    @classmethod
    def names(cls) -> List[str]:
        return [c.value._display for c in cls]

    @classmethod
    def __json_schema__(cls, schema: Dict[str, Any]) -> str:
        breakpoint()
        del schema["description"]

        schema["type"] = "string"

        return json.dumps(schema)


class OneOfEnum(ExtendedEnum):
    @classmethod
    def __json_schema__(cls, schema: Dict[str, Any]) -> str:
        del schema["enum"]

        schema["oneOf"] = [
            {"const": value, "title": name}
            for value, name in zip(cls.values(), cls.names())
        ]

        return json.dumps(schema)


class AssignedSex(OneOfEnum):
    male = ExtendedStr("male", "Male")
    female = ExtendedStr("female", "Female")
    other = ExtendedStr("other", "Other")
    unknown = ExtendedStr("unknown", "Unknown")
```

I've tried different methods in the custom class. I've also tried different customizations to the pydantic base model, however the details I need for this are at the class level and not the model level.

Pydantic v1 with this logic used to output:

```
    "AssignedSex": {
      "title": "AssignedSex",
      "type": "string",
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "const": "male",
          "title": "Male"
        },
        {
          "const": "female",
          "title": "Female"
        },
        {
          "const": "other",
          "title": "Other"
        },
        {
          "const": "unknown",
          "title": "Unknown"
        }
      ]
    }
```

While Pydantic v2 has reverted to the standard representation:

```
    "AssignedSex": {
      "enum": ["male", "female", "other", "unknown"],
      "title": "AssignedSex",
      "type": "string"
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ultimately found the answer. Rather than using `__json_schema__` you have to implement `__get_pydantic_json_schema__`. This required a little code massaging, but the transformation turned into this:

```
class ExtendedEnum(ExtendedStr, Enum):
    def __init__(self, value: ExtendedStr) -> None:
        self.value._display = value._display

    @classmethod
    def values(cls) -> list[str]:
        return [c.value for c in cls]

    @classmethod
    def names(cls) -> list[str]:
        return [c.value._display for c in cls]

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(
        cls, core_schema: CoreSchema, handler: GetJsonSchemaHandler
    ) -> JsonSchemaValue:
        json_schema = handler(core_schema)
        json_schema["type"] = "string"
        return json_schema


class OneOfEnum(ExtendedEnum):
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(
        cls, core_schema: CoreSchema, handler: GetJsonSchemaHandler
    ) -> JsonSchemaValue:
        json_schema = handler(core_schema)
        del json_schema["enum"]
        json_schema["oneOf"] = [
            {"const": value, "title": name}
            for value, name in zip(cls.values(), cls.names())
        ]
        return json_schema
```

The output schema now matches what I was originally wanting.